# The fade transition between slides need to slow on owlcarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am using owlcarousel2, The fade transition between slides is still too quick. When one image changes to the next, it needs to be slower. (I am not referring to how long a single slide is displayed, just the transition speed). Where i have this option

```
autoplaySpeed: 13000,
autoplayTimeout:5000
```

Comment: this transitions every 20 secs http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/w7h28fhc/ i think just use autoPlay (without the Speed/Timeout)

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce the autoplay to e.g. 2000, it should play a lot faster (vice versa, if you want it to be slower, increase the autoplayspeed from 13000 to e.g. 20000, but at the moment it's the 5000 that seems to be counted for the transition, so increase that to maybe 8000 - 8secs)

See my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/njvbLdaf/) (it's different but it's owl carousel)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay:2000, //Set AutoPlay to 2 seconds
        dots: true,
        items: 2,
        itemsDesktop: [100, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [200, 3]
    });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item {
    margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page {
    display: inline-block;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #869791;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.2/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="owl-demo">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

(snippet somehow doesn't work, but fiddle works, correct the snippet if you spot the error, thx)